# Populate Existing Map from SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

Every example of SOQL queries being used (the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm), for example) shows a new map being populated with the results of an SOQL query like this -

`Map<ID, Account> m = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10])`

I'd like to populate a map that's been created outside of one method in my class, so that I can retrieve values from it in another method.

But when I try

```
Map<Id,ProjectxOpp__c> pxOs = [SELECT Id,Opportunity__r.Account.Name
                                 FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                WHERE Opportunity__c IN :stage4EuOpps.keySet()];
```

I get an error

> Illegal assignment from List to Map

I know that I could create a map in my method with the results of the query & then copy that map to the map outside my method but this seems like a waste of time.

Is it possible to populate an existing map from an SOQL query?

Comment: The example from the documentation is correct as well, but you need to use all of it `Map<Id,ProjectxOpp__c> pxOS = new Map<Id,ProjectxOpp__c>([SELECT...]);`

Comment: @FernandoGavinho thanks but it looks like you might have misread my question. I was looking for a way to avoid creating a new map to store the results of my query.

Comment: Oh, true. Sorry =/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this, from the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) they say that [`putAll`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_putAll_2) can take an sObjectArray (list of sObjects)

```
pxOs.putAll([SELECT Id,Opportunity__r.Account.Name
                                 FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                WHERE Opportunity__c IN :stage4EuOpps.keySet()]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's compiled. I'll accept this answer as soon as the 7 minutes is up.